# FFmpeg Video First Frame Time Code value

Tags: ffmpeg, timecodes

I would like to ask someone how knows FFmpeg good

[image]

As you can see I already know how to set timecodes that contain in green borders,
but I don't know is there any opportunity set the Video timecode.
Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only possible with ffmpeg if you are ready to re-encode the video stream as MPEG-2 e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v mpeg2video -gop_timecode "03:04:05:06" output
```